# godaddy vds SPF and Domain Keys issue

Tags: email, godaddy, vds

I have a question about godaddy's mail server.
I have a VDS at godaddy and I want to configure my mail server to send mail to yahoo in inbox, not in spam. I have configured SPF, DomainKeys and DKIM, but only DKIM passed the test:

SPF check:          neutral
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    neutral
SpamAssassin check: ham

I have notice that godaddy send mail with n1nlvphout01.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net and I think this is the problem. But what can I do?

This is a sample (I replace my domain with mydomain.com):

```
*************************************
Return-Path: <test@mydomain.com>
Received: from n1nlvphout01.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net (188.121.43.195) by verifier.port25.com (PowerMTA(TM) v3.6a1) id hrh05q0hse8f for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 11 Nov 2010 14:13:33 -0500 (envelope-from <test@mydomain.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com smtp.mail=test@mydomain.com; mfrom=neutral (SPF-Result: Neutral);
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com header.From=test@mydomain.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed);
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com header.d=mydomain.com; dkim=pass (matches From: test@mydomain.com);
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com header.From=test@mydomain.com; pra=neutral (SPF-Result: Neutral);
Received: (qmail 2584 invoked from network); 11 Nov 2010 19:13:12 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO ip-188-121-50-207.ip.secureserver.net) (188.121.50.207)
  by n1nlvphout01.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net (188.121.43.195) with ESMTP; 11 Nov 2010 19:13:12 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=mydomain.com; s=mail; h=MIME-Version:Content-Type:
 Content-Transfer-Encoding:Date:From:To:Subject:Message-ID; bh=bc
 GnigHKQ1COL7O5IRBTZm1iF+SLByfqOZo2vYgpCBg=; b=R7KSjZcuV97tAh+9Ua
 AiBDxQXwFSDvrsQa+69L+EX8jKWqaaoPLKcquSiBWQ3XgoMFa5Ep7IxnWyAjvzJ8
 xpMzLiqmTYsY472SrC/NbiXuV6V9racIEOYWHHSyfi2TKfptnQv84pSOL/4pLUj/
 Ddxy6Cw+Pm+9wIFrvnJmEBJHo=
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([127.0.0.1] helo=www.mydomain.com)
 by ip-188-121-50-207.ip.secureserver.net with esmtpa (Exim 4.69)
 (envelope-from <test@mydomain.com>)
 id 1PGca8-0003UJ-5H; Thu, 11 Nov 2010 12:13:12 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8;
 format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Thu, 11 Nov 2010 12:13:12 -0700
From: <test@mydomain.com>
To: <autorespond+dkim@dk.elandsys.com>, <sa-test@sendmail.net>,
 <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>
Subject: test
Message-ID: <1a62d2ead49f8190a8447b4eb82dc570@mydomain.com>
X-Sender: test@mydomain.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.4.2

 test
*************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo bulk email sender help is at
http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/forms_index.html